# Are 'less amounts' and 'lesser amounts' interchangeable?

Tags: usage

I referred to a host of dictionaries, but I couldn't find any difference in the meaning between ***less amounts*** and ***lesser amounts***.

For example, in the following examples, are ***less amounts*** and ***lesser amounts*** interchangeable?

"Other drivers – most of whom worked significantly less amounts of time – would receive an average of $53.02." (The Guardian - Tech)

"Lesser amounts are found in meats, nuts, eggs, cereals and cheese." (The New York Times -Health)

Comment: I think the first example is actually a mistake.  *Lesser amounts of time* or *less time* would be more fluent.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use **amounts of time**, I think **lesser** is a better choice in the first example:

> Other drivers – most of whom worked significantly lesser amounts of time – would receive an average of $53.02.

However, an even better solution it to strike **amounts of time** because it's understood that people work on a clock:

> Other drivers – most of whom worked significantly **less** <strike>amounts of time</strike> – would receive an average of $53.02."

In the second example, if you use some form of *less*, you have to use **lesser**:

> "Lesser amounts are found in meats, nuts, eggs, cereals and cheese."

But in this case, an even better choice might be to use **smaller**

> Smaller amounts are found in meats, nuts, eggs, cereals and chooese.

Answer (score 0):

No, the two are not interchangeable.

"Less" is used only with uncountable nouns, but "amounts" is countable, so the grammar of "less amounts" is bad.

"Fewer amounts" is grammatically correct, but it doesn't mean "lesser amounts". It means, "the number of different amounts is lower".